# Laravel 9 - using vite to do a js import within a blade template

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying out Laravel 9 with Vite, but without(!) a frontend framework (like Vue or React).
I am trying to make a reusable js module that I could use/load in different Blade templates.

So I created a file '*menu-btn-toggle.js*' in '*resources/js/components/utilities*'.

```
export class MenuBtnToggle
{
    constructor() {
        console.log('MenuBtnToggle');
    }
}
```

I then created a '*utilities.js*' file in '*resources/js/components*'.

```
import './utilities/menu-btn-toggle';
```

I then updated the '*app.js*' file in '*resources/js*'

```
import './bootstrap';
import './components/utilities';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();
```

So far, this seems to be working (?). Atleast, i think so. Vite is not giving me any errors so far (yay!)

But then I try to import the module in a blade template, but I can't get it to work.
So at the bottom of my blade template, I added this:

```
<script type="module">
    import MenuBtnToggle from 'menu-btn-toggle';

    new MenuBtnToggle();
</script>
```

But this gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “menu-btn-toggle”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.

But when I add one of the examples, the error changes to:

> Loading module from “[local_dev_url]/menu-btn-toggle” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

as it isn't be able to find the module. It returns a 404.

Is it even possible do to want I want without a frontend framework? Or am I not seeing something obvious? I have experience with php, unfortunately not (enough) with Laravel and Vite.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Laravel, this works:

```
import { helper_fn } from "{{ Vite::asset('resources/js/helpers.js') }}"
```

but it prints out the whole URL, which seems a bit overkill. But I could not get it to work using aliases or relative paths. And then again.. this would not work with older browsers which do not support `import`.

Comment: Importantly, this also works in development with `npm run dev` which the other answers do not.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck into almost same situation where we are not able to use import statement inside our blade files using Vite. We commonly get

> Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier
> “menu-btn-toggle”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”,
> “../” or “/”.

or We get 404 Blocked error nearly same as

> Loading module from “[local_dev_url]/menu-btn-toggle” was blocked
> because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

When importing external npm packages or modules, we need to put them in windows object just like you did above for Alpine

```
window.Alpine = Alpine;
```

But for your specific case problem you must do following

1)Inside menu-btn-toggle.js

```
export class MenuBtnToggle
{
    constructor() {
        console.log('MenuBtnToggle');
    }
}
```

2)Inside utilities.js

```
import {MenuBtnToggle} from "./utilities/menu-btn-toggle";
window.MenuBtnToggle = MenuBtnToggle;
```

3. And then finally inside your app.js

   import './components/utilities';
4. Now inside your .blade file, there is no need to import the MenuBtnToggle
   instead just do it like

   new MenuBtnToggle();

No need to use `import MenuBtnToggle from 'menu-btn-toggle';` in blade.
Important thing is to import your app.js file properly inside .blade file through vite

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css','resources/js/app.js'])
```

And it works. It has worked when reproducing same files/setup as yours.

Comment: but this way, you have to import all of your small modules in app.js, and they are imported for all pages, all of the time, which defeats the purpose of having small modules

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a function :

in *resources/js/components/utilities/menu-btn-toggle.js* :

```js
function MenuBtnToggle
{
    console.log('MenuBtnToggle');
}

window.MenuBtnToggle = MenuBtnToggle;
```

If you don't define *window.MenuBtnToggle* line, you can see in console error like :
*Uncaught ReferenceError: MenuBtnToggle is not defined*

in *resources/view/myView.blade.php* :

```php
@section(…)

@vite('resources/js/components/utilies/menu-btn-toggle.js')
//… you can now call you js function
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was to call a object method from a script inside the blade file.

Solved in this way.

*Inside app.js:*

```
import {My_object} from "./My_object.js";
window.My_object = My_object;
```

*Inside the object:*

```
export var My_object = {
    /**
    * Something
    **/
}
```

Thanks to everybody.